# Why does animating a modal view controller onscreen cause a crash here?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

This piece of code works fine. However, if I change the `animated` parameter to YES it crashes.

```
AccountViewController *accViewController = [[AccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Account" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:accViewController animated:NO];
[accViewController release];
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: can you provide us the console log (what exception is throwed?)

Comment: there will be - turn breakpoints on and you might be able to see it.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?  Does it freeze, close the app, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the release call.  Although I would assume that push should retain, I can't recall for sure and i am not sure *when* it retains.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this while any other animation is going on? I've seen crashes here in that type of situation (for example, while one view is being dismissed, pushing or presenting another will crash.)